In a hierarchical SQL query, how to remove the children of a row that does not satisfy a condition?
SELECT rep.*,
       rank() OVER (PARTITION BY 
                    rep.ROOT_ASSEMBLY_ID,rep.ASSEMBLY_ID
                    ORDER BY CASE WHEN rep.state_code = 'PUBLISH' THEN 1 ELSE 2 END) rnk
FROM
    (SELECT T.* ,CONNECT_BY_ROOT T.ASSEMBLY_ID ROOT_ASSEMBLY_ID
       FROM TABLE T
       START WITH T.SCENARIO_ID = <SCENARIO_ID>
       CONNECT BY PRIOR T.COMPONENT_ID = T.ASSEMBLY_ID
    )rep WHERE rep.rnk = 1

Above query builds the hierarchy of Item Structure where the components of Assembly A are parents of other assemblies. In that hierarchy I want to select only those assemblies which are ranked as 1 as per the "STATE_CODE" which can be "PUBLISH" or "ROLLUP" for the parent nodes in the hierarchy. I am able to acheive it with RANK function but I am not able to restrict the child rows for the assemblies with RANK other than 1. Any input on how we can restrict the child rows by bringing the rank function within the CONNECT BY OPERATOR so query executes CONNECT BY operation only when the assembly is ranked 1
Edit:The ranking function uses the ROOT NODE of the hierarchy in the PARTITION BY clause of the RAN function , so I cannot first create the RANKING and THEN use CONNECT BY

Please [edit] the question to include a [MRE] with: the CREATE TABLE and INSERT statements for your sample data; an English (not code) explanation of the logic you are trying to implement; and the expected output for your sample data. At the moment, your question is difficult to follow because we cannot see what your are starting with nor what you expect as the output and the explanation focuses on the code (which doesn't do what you want).

By using CONNECT_BY_ROOT T.ASSEMBLY_ID within the PARTITION BY clause of the RANK() function, each node's rank is computed relative to its root node in the hierarchy.
SELECT rep.*
FROM (
    SELECT T.*,
           RANK() OVER (
               PARTITION BY CONNECT_BY_ROOT T.ASSEMBLY_ID
               ORDER BY CASE WHEN T.STATE_CODE = 'PUBLISH' THEN 1 ELSE 2 END
           ) AS rnk
    FROM TABLE T
    START WITH T.SCENARIO_ID = <SCENARIO_ID>
    CONNECT BY PRIOR T.COMPONENT_ID = T.ASSEMBLY_ID
)
WHERE rnk = 1;


I had tried the method above but the ranking function uses the ROOT NODE of the hierarchy in the PARTITION BY clause to fetch the correct ranking , so I cannot first create the RANKING and THEN use CONNECT BY. Sorry for missing out this point. I have edited the question now. Thanks and appreciate your response!

@Arcs - Thanks for the clarification. Please see my edited answer above.


In a hierarchical SQL query, how to remove the children of a row that does not satisfy a condition?

You appear to want to start with rows that, for each assembly_id with the given scenario_id, have the state_code of 'PUBLISH' and, if there are zero rows with that state_code then use 'ROLLUP' and then find the descendants that have the same state_code as their parent.
To do that, generate the RANK before using the hierarchical query and filter on RANK in the START WITH clause and then in the CONNECT BY clause ensure that successive children have the same state_code as its parent.
SELECT T.*,
       CONNECT_BY_ROOT T.ASSEMBLY_ID AS root_assembly_id
FROM   (
  SELECT t.*,
         RANK() OVER (
           PARTITION BY assembly_id
           ORDER BY CASE state_code WHEN 'PUBLISH' THEN 1 ELSE 2 END
         ) AS rank
  FROM   table_name t
)
START WITH
       scenario_id = :SCENARIO_ID
AND    rnk = 1
CONNECT BY
       PRIOR component_id = assembly_id
AND    PRIOR state_code   = state_code

You have not provided any sample data or expected output so this is impossible to test.
